# I can't get an ImageReaderByFormatName("jpeg-lossless")

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg, dicom

I am trying to decode a lossless jpeg using JAI_ImageIO library and the following java call:

```
ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpeg-lossless").hasNext()
```

results in "null".

NOTE: I have the JAI_ImageIO jar installed to my jre/lib/ext directory.

I don't know if the JPEG reader is sufficient to read lossless jpegs or if another reader is required to be installed.

When I enumerate the FormatNames, i.e.:

```
ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()
```

I get the following formats:

```
[raw, jpeg, tif, WBMP, PNM, JPG, DICOM, wbmp, JPEG, PNG, jpeg 2000, 
tiff, BMP, JPEG2000, RAW, jpeg2000, GIF, TIF, TIFF, jpg, bmp, pnm, 
png, JPEG 2000, gif]
```

I get the following runtime exception when I try to use the JPEG2000 reader:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: File is neither valid JP2 file nor valid JPEG 2000 codestream
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KReadState.initializeRead(J2KReadState.java:696)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KReadState.<init>(J2KReadState.java:209)
at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageReader.read(J2KImageReader.java:449)
at javax.imageio.ImageReader.read(ImageReader.java:940)
```

When I try to

```
ImageIO.read(file)
```

directly I get a an org.dcm4cheri.image.ConfigurationException.

Comment: Does lossless JPEG need a separate reader? I thought the benefit was that the file could be read by any JPEG reader.

Comment: JPEG and JPEG 2000 are totally different formats, similar only in name. They both have lossless modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to my particular problem and I believe it will solve the more general problem of how to install JAI_ImageIO properly at least on *NIX based operating system.

After reading the following ([Obscure place on the WWW](http://markmail.org/message/oleojchwhns52dlv#query%3ajavax.imageio.IIOException%3a%20Unsupported%20JPEG%20process%3a%20SOF%20type%200xc3+page:1+mid%3aclpbe5clus6yd7oh+state%3aresults)) and attempting all 3 installation alternatives of JAI_ImageIO described [here](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html#Linux).  (I should've also made mention that I am running on a Debian 6.0 64bit platform.)

After settling with the [manual](http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/INSTALL-jai_imageio.html#Manual) "installation type" I realized that my LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable wasn't being picked up.  So I decided to force the issue and add a soft link to the libclib_jiio.so in my /usr/lib.  Lo and behold it worked.

I used the code provided [here](http://markmail.org/message/oleojchwhns52dlv#query%3ajavax.imageio.IIOException%3a%20Unsupported%20JPEG%20process%3a%20SOF%20type%200xc3+page:1+mid%3apjqcqjouixztervb+state%3aresults) to determine if my JAI_ImageIO was installed properly, and when it is installed properly you should see a "JPEG-LOSSLESS" formats/providers in the output!

Thanks for the suggestions.  I will try to expand the question to make it more general to the problem of installing JAI_ImageIO pro

Comment: Could you please explain your solution step by step? I didn't get it.

Comment: Yes if jai is installed in that case it ll work... is ther any way without jai i can do so?? because if i use jai native library its crashing my application.... @Reuben Peter-Paul

Answer (score 0):

I do not think jpeg-lossless is a valid format for JAI. Try listing your available formats:

```
String[] formats =  ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames();
for ( String format : formats ) {
    System.out.println(format);
}
```

I think what you actually want is "JPEG2000".

Have you also just tried ImageIO.read(file). That should successfully read DICOM files if you have JAI installed.

Comment: Thanks but no dice.  I'm expanding the question with the results from your suggestions.

Comment: JPEG2000 has a lossless mode, but it's separate from JPEG lossless. Two totally different animals.